# Membership.ValidateUser returns false on first call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I have a bit of a peculiar problem which I don't really understand..

For my login I am using the following method:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                return Redirect("/");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.Global.IncorrectUserName);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

The weird thing is that on the first login attempt the secont if statement (Membership.ValidateUser) returns false. At the second attempt it returns true and the user gets access to the application.
I have found similar questions, but none of the answers there have worked for me.. :(

What I now would like to know is:
1: why does this happen?
2: How can I correct this so that the user gets logged in at the first attempt?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this and replace your code inside the `if Membership.ValidateUser` block.
`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);`
`return Redirect("/");`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it gives the same result.. :(